# React forEach function not rendering HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with a function that renders a list of music credits. `titles` is an object of strings and `props.current.credits` is an object of arrays (they're drawn from a much larger JSON, so changing the data structures is not an option).

```
const titles = {
    featuring: "Featuring",
    recorded: "Recorded at",
    samples: "Samples",
    ...etc
}

props.current.credits = {
    "writers": ["John Doe", "Sally Singer"],
    "recorded": [{
        "studio": "ABC Studios",
        "city": "Houston, Texas"
    }],
    ...etc
}
```

The function only renders the `h2` tags, but not the `p` tags within the `forEach` code blocks. When I test the `forEach` blocks by logging `name` to the console, the values appear, so I'm completely stuck as to what the problem could be. Some insight on this would be appreciated.

```js
const Credit = props => {
    const credit = type => {
        if (props.current.credits.hasOwnProperty(type)) {
            if (type === "recorded") {
                return (
                    <div className="credit">
                        <h2>{titles[type]}</h2>
                        {
                            props.current.credits[type].forEach(name => {
                                return (
                                    <p className="location">
                                        <span className="studio">{name.studio}</span>
                                        <span className="city">{name.city}</span>
                                    </p>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            }

            if (type === "samples" || type === "interpolates") {
                return (
                    <div className="credit">
                        <h2>{titles[type]}</h2>
                        {
                            props.current.credits[type].forEach(name => {
                                return (
                                    <p className="location">
                                        <span className="studio">{name.title}</span>
                                        <span className="city">{{ __html: name.info }}</span>
                                    </p>
                                )
                            })
                        }
                    </div>
                )
            }

            return (
                <div className="credit">
                    <h2>{titles[type]}</h2>
                    {
                        props.current.credits[type].forEach(name => {
                            return (
                                <p>{name}</p>
                            )
                        })
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    return (
        <div>
            {credit("samples")}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: use map method instead of forEach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official docs, [you should use `map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#rendering-multiple-components).

So an example would be:

```
{
  props.current.credits[type].map((name) => {
    return (
      <p className="location">
        <span className="studio">{name.studio}</span>
        <span className="city">{name.city}</span>
      </p>
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Lol ... one of those times you spend so long trying to solve a problem and the solution is so simple. Thanks for the refresher!

Answer (score 1):

**forEach** method does not return anything. It returns **undefined**. Use **map** instead. **map method** always returns **an array** at the end.